# Ordering with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

With the ng-options shown below, the orderBy doesn't seem to do anything.

```
<tr ng-repeat="variable in variables">
  <td>
    <select ng-model="variable.type" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in variableTypes | orderBy:value"></select>
  </td>
```

variableTypes there is a simple associative array with the key of a number (bound to variable.type) and the values are the textual display.  I've put both key and value after the orderBy to no avail.

Comment: _"a simple associative array with the key of a number (bound to variable.type) and the values are the textual display. I've put both key and value after the orderBy to no avail."_ - It's unclear to me whether a JS Array or Object is being used as your data structure. If you're using an Object, `orderBy` won't work since Objects don't store data in a guaranteed order.

Comment: Please post your data structure, JS has no associative arrays.

Comment: For example, $scope.variableTypes = {'1':'Bob', '2':'Frank'}

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to use 'orderBy' with associative arrays.

An alternative approach would be to use a normal array with items that have key/value properties:

```
$scope.listSortable = [];

angular.forEach(associativeArray, function(value, key) {
    $scope.listSortable.push({ key: key, value: value });
});
```

HTML

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in listSortable | orderBy: 'value'">
        {{item.key}}
        {{item.value}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how to apply that change to my ng-options, shown above?  I'm really new to AngularJS and so this is still pretty confusing.  Thanks.